# How do I fix this error: MapFileParser.sh: Permission denied Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: c++, command-line, objective-c-runtime

I cannot figure out how to fix this issue. I am on Xcode 15.1, and I do not have Pods on here. I have seen that as a solution, but I would like to know if there is a work around for fixing this. Any help would be appreciated!

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall and still same issue. The MapFileParser.sh: Permission denied. I am not sure what else to do.

Comment: You may have to inspect this shell script to determine where and why it fails to figure out the permissions problem,

Comment: ***I have tried to uninstall and reinstall and still same issue*** I expect reinstalling is unlikely to fix the permissions problem.

Comment: Yes, I was trying anything based off other posts I have seen. This is the only part it fails on. Everything else runs fine.

Comment: I expect you will have to look at the contents of `MapFileParser.sh`  to understand the problem.

Comment: This is weird. I used this chmod: Path to MapFileParser.sh: No such file or directory. Now it says there is no such file or directory, but I have a permission denied.